# No Network Security Config specified, using platform default for android login design

Tags: android, android-volley

this is my first time to ask question as I really encounters a big problems, I am on the way to develop a android login/register page that can communicate with remote server, I followed some tutorials, but I cannot get the ideal results even I follows lots of tutorials, I hope someone can help me out,

Here is my code, I first create a mysql database in localhost, and I write the following php code to connect android application and dababase:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "myaccount", "mypassword", "mytest");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, username, age, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $username, $age, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

I then create a android application that using volley framework to handle with database, Here is the code of "register" button, when I filled information and click it, I hope it can send data tp mysql,

```
RegisterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String name = etName.getText().toString();
            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            final int age = Integer.parseInt(etAge.getText().toString());
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if (success) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, username, age, password, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);
        }
    });
```

I also list the `RegisterRequest` function code as follows:

```
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {
private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://my computer ipv4/Register11.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public RegisterRequest(String name, String username, int age, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
    super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("name", name);
    params.put("age", age + "");
    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("password", password);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
}
```

I personally think I've finished all the information that needed, but when I test my andriod app, I cannot send data to database, I've checked my code for the entire day and still cannot solve it, Here I post my `register` page，
[register page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiHL5.png) ,       [register page after finish information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uCoz.png)

When I click "register" button, the application will give a warning of

```
No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
```

I understand this is not error, but my app was stopped here, I mean, When I Click the button, app has no response and only show the above warning, also, the information is not send to database, I've tried to solve it for a long time, but still get error, I am hoping someone can help me out. I would very appreciate!

Comment: maybe this can help you. 
https://github.com/mirjalal/Android_and_WebService

Answer (score 0):

From Network security configuration doc by Google, you can fix this by adding this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    ...
    <application
        ...
        android:usesClearTextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

To your AndroidManifest.xml file

For more information, you can check the Google doc so Network Security Configuration here - "https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config"

Answer (score 0):

Change in Manifest file helped me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    ...
    <application
        ...
        android:usesClearTextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```